# What is this bit for with a hole in the end? [pic]

Tags: tools

I just came across this bit in my toolbox, which I'm fairly sure came with an installers drill bit (54" long flexible bit, with a hole in the end for pulling wires back through).

[image: mystery bit]

It's a standard screw driver bit, tapered at the end (though not enough to actually be a flathead bit) and a hole through it. Any ideas what this is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be used for pulling or twisting something.  For example, you would attach a wire to it, then engage the drill or manually rotate, thus twisting or rotating the wire.  It would also be used for fishing the wire thought a wall.  The rotation would allow it to more easily pass.

Answer (score 5):

If you hadn't said it came with the installer's bit, I would have guessed it was for twisting [safety wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_wire):

[image: Safety wire]

I guess it's still possible, but it seems like an unlikely thing to include with an installer's bit.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say for sure, but I would say it's for twisting pairs/groups of wires together.

Answer (score 1):

It can be adapted to many uses but its main intended purpose is to drive threaded cup hooks and similar fittings into their pilot holes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're meant to push something like a screwdriver through the hole, and then use that as a handle (lots of leverage). Of course this could damage your screwdriver if you weren't careful...

Answer (score 0):

ive been looking for that piece for awhile, not sure what the real purpose of it is but I use it to put a twist in the phone wires at work. that piece did come with a fish net looking contraption but I toss it just use as a wire twister cause it snap into the drill easily.